# Google Test output report append

Tags: googletest

I am using GTest in VC++ for unit testing. I have 5 test suits. I want to generate test report of results returned by Google test.

I used ::testing::GTEST_FLAGS(output) = "xml:filename.xml" before InitGoogleTest method.

Report generated but for only last test suit executed. every time it's overwrite test suit results.

my code looks as per below:

```
::testing::GTEST_FLAGS(output) = "xml:filename.xml"

switch(tessuite)
{

CASE TEST1:
  ::testing::GTEST_FILTER("TEST1*");

  RUN_ALL_TESTS();

CASE TEST2:

  ::testing::GTEST_FILTER("TEST2*");

  RUN_ALL_TESTS();

CASE TEST3:

  ::testing::GTEST_FILTER("TEST3*");

  RUN_ALL_TESTS();

CASE TEST4:

  ::testing::GTEST_FILTER("TEST4*");

  RUN_ALL_TESTS();

CASE TEST5:

  ::testing::GTEST_FILTER("TEST5*");

  RUN_ALL_TESTS(); 

}
```

When I run the program filename.xml report generated for last test suit. not appending the results of all test-suits. How to append it.?

I want to generate single report for all test-suits. anyone help me ?

Comment: Are missing breaks in switch-case by design?

Comment: And please explain: writing `CASE`, not `case` is just typo?

Comment: break is written in the original code base. 

Here given the example code. so I missed to write here.

Yes. Writing CASE is just typo mistake..