# Google test: How to make a single xml report from multiple test suit run?

Tags: xml, googletest

I am using the gTest in ubuntu to execute component level tests. I have to execute 10 test suites and take the execution report in XML.
My bash script to run the gTest application looks like below:

export GTEST_OUTPUT="xml:${ARTIFACTS_DIR}/test/gtest/test-report.xml"

execute background_process1

execute gTest with filter=filter1

-----execution finished------

execute background_process2

execute gTest with filter=filter2

-----execution finished------

.....
.....

execute background_process10

execute gTest with filter=filter10

-----execution finished------

So my problem here is, for each execution, the "test-report.xml" is overwritten, so I am ending up with the report of the last executed test only.
I want a test report that includes the report of all the execution.
Yes, it is possible to have 10 test reports for 10 test suites.

Is there any way to have a single report in this case? or how to append different XML results into one?
There was a similar question in StackOverFlow ([Google Test output report append](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40716759/google-test-output-report-append)), but without any answer.

Any help would be appreciated
Thank you

Comment: How do you start the test executable? It doesn't show anywhere in your listing.

Comment: I am starting the test executable from a bash script.
There I have a function named RunGtest() that will take 2 arguments: 
1 -- Background process name
2 -- gTest filter

This RunGtest() function will be called multiple times with different arguments. So that each time different test suites are executed with different environment.
Command used inside the function to start the gTest application is : ./gtest_app --gtest_filter=*"$filter"

The report generation is initiated as : export GTEST_OUTPUT="xml:${ARTIFACTS_DIR}/test/gtest/test-report.xml"

Comment: Then please rewrite your question, so we don't have to guess what you are doing. Also, read how to format code pieces in questions: https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code